What elements should I consider to determine efficiency with the MongoDB profiler?
I need to make a query with aggregations in MongoDB. I've already built 2 different aggregation pipelines that give me the result I need, so I have to decide which one to stick with.
I was reading the documentation and I saw that MongoDB has a built-in profiler for this purpose. So what I've done is run the aggregations and review the profiler results getting something like this:
{
  op: 'command',
  ns: 'auth.users',
  command: {
    explain: {
      aggregate: 'users',
      pipeline: [
        {
          '$match': {
            'accessControl.organization': ObjectId('6638e821b35e766556ebc5de')
          }
        },
        {
          '$addFields': {
            accessControl: {
              '$arrayElemAt': [
                {
                  '$filter': {
                    input: '$accessControl',
                    as: 'item',
                    cond: {
                      '$eq': [
                        '$$item.organization',
                        ObjectId('6638e821b35e766556ebc5de')
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          '$group': {
            _id: {
              role: '$accessControl.role.name',
              id: '$accessControl.role.id'
            },
            users: {
              '$push': {
                _id: '$_id',
                disabled: '$disabled',
                email: '$email',
                emailVerified: '$emailVerified',
                name: '$name',
                accessControl: [
                  '$accessControl'
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          '$project': {
            _id: 0,
            role: '$_id',
            users: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      cursor: {}
    },
    verbosity: 'queryPlanner',
    lsid: {
      id: UUID('c35ecb9e-abc5-4286-ac78-5d74ea6d9bf4')
    },
    '$db': 'auth'
  },
  numYield: 0,
  queryHash: '7A34A1A0',
  planCacheKey: '7A34A1A0',
  queryFramework: 'classic',
  locks: {
    FeatureCompatibilityVersion: {
      acquireCount: {
        r: 2
      }
    },
    Global: {
      acquireCount: {
        r: 2
      }
    }
  },
  flowControl: {},
  responseLength: 2437,
  protocol: 'op_msg',
  cpuNanos: 799390,
  millis: 0,
  planSummary: 'COLLSCAN',
  planningTimeMicros: 200,
  ts: 2024-05-14T21:22:23.875Z,
  client: '172.18.0.1',
  appName: 'MongoDB Compass',
  allUsers: [
    {
      user: 'abc123',
      db: 'admin'
    }
  ],
  user: 'abc123@admin'
}

I'm not really sure how to interpret this to decide which one to use. I understand that millis determines the number of milliseconds it takes to execute the query, but in both cases I get 0 (which causes me a bit of confusion). Maybe I need to add more users since I'm trying some randomly generated fake documents. So I decided to be guided by cpuNanos, which as I understand, is the amount of cpu used in nanoseconds. But in both cases the values range between 300,000 and 1,000,000 (sometimes higher values in the first pipeline and sometimes higher values in the second). So what should I do to decide? Should I run them many times, average, and see which one is greater? Or what other field can help me decide.

Try using explain with the "executionStats" or "allPlansExecution" option.  The profiler will give you details about a specific run, but very little about the plan.  Also try creating an index on "accessControl.organization" and see if explain shows that as more performant.

The millis: 0 just means the query completed in less than 1ms, which probably means the collection size is small enough to fit entirely in cache.

Using the explain functionality I do see consistent changes from one pipeline to another. In the Query Performance Summary section the execution time field is faster in my first pipeline (the second one is usually double... 8ms...16ms...). What does that execution time refer to? Now I will test the index. Thank you so much

(I increased the number of documents too)
